# How to connect to Wi-Fi network in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa

tl;dr After reading the Arch wiki articles on [installation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide), [wireless setup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_Setup) and [WPA supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_Supplicant), trying the suggestions below and a host of forum threads, I'm unable to get *either* of the following cards to connect to my wireless network when booting the Arch Linux 2013-09-01 ISO:

- [Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003MTTJOY/) (ID 7392:7811)
- Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter aka. [Bolse® 300Mbps Wifi Wireless N USB Micro Mini Adapter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bolse%C2%AE-300Mbps-Wireless-Micro-Adapter/dp/B00DTZYHX4/) (ID 0bda:8178)

---

Approach 1 (default):

The default way of doing this is supposed to be just [`systemctl stop dhcpcd.service`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide#Connect_to_the_internet) followed by [`wifi-menu`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide#Wireless). It finds the network:

```
[SSID] + wpa 10
```

After a timeout it reports that the connection failed. If I run `wifi-menu` a *second* time it doesn't ask for a password, but when finished it finally gives some debug hints:

```
Job for netctl@wlp0s29f7u5\x2dBTHub4\x2dGRK6.service failed. See 'systemctl status netctl@wlp0s29f7u5\x2dBTHub4\x2dGRK6.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

The former reports that the service is "loaded" but not "active" (literally `inactive (dead)`). The latter says:

```
WPA association/authentication failed for interface 'wlp0s29f7u5'
```

Does this mean the key in `/etc/netctl/wlp0s29f7u5-BTHub4-GRK6` is wrong? I can't tell when programs want the *actual* Wi-Fi password and when they want something like the `psk` value from `wpa_passphrase` (`man 5 netctl.profile` doesn't say, for example).

---

Approach 2 ([`wpa_supplicant`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant) and `wpa_passphrase` as per [deeraf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91378/3645) and [warl0ck](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92808/3645)'s suggestions and the wiki page):

```
# echo 'ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant' > wifi.conf
# wpa_passphrase essid passphrase >> wifi.conf
# wpa_supplicant -B -i interface -c wifi.conf
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
# dhcpcd -A interface
[...]
timed out
exited
```

---

I tried connecting with `iw` directly, but got some strange output:

```
# iw dev wlp0s26f7u5 connect [SSID]
command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
```

Comment: Have you tried to test the stick with a different distro, for example an Ubuntu live system, just to establish that it works in Linux? Is there something interesting in your `dmesg` output, maybe something that's pointing to a firmware issue?

Comment: Interestingly, on Ubuntu 13.04 it shows up on the networking menu, but is displayed as "Disconnected".

Comment: So you can't connect on Ubuntu either? Have you considered just using another WiFi USB stick? That may be an easier solution to your problem.

Comment: I guess. [The latest driver](http://www.edimax.co.uk/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=328&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=44) only supports kernels up to 2.6.33. Too bad it's almost impossible to find trustworthy sources of Linux compatible hardware.

Comment: Bought a Bolse micro USB adapter - Let's see if that can compete. At least they prominently claim Linux support on the product page, which is a good sign.

Comment: I usually use `dhcpcd -d -n interface` - it gives you more information. Also it is a good idea to check the state of the interface with `iwconfig` first. Ideally 1) run `wpa_supplicant` in a separate terminal **without** the `-B` option, but with `-d` to get more debugging info, i.e.: `wpa_supplicant -d -i interface -c wifi.conf -Dwext `; 2) in another terminal, check `iwconfig`; 3) in another terminal run. Alternatively, before all this you might want to give [`wicd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wicd) a try.

Comment: yeah, as @jeight mentioned in his answer, why are you stopping `dhcpd.service`? this certainly isn't the "default" way to do it. also, the fact that you get the WPA error and that `wifi-menu` picks up networks suggests that there's nothing wrong with the network card drivers, IMHO.

Comment: @peterph `wpa_supplicant` output `EAPOL authentication completed successfully` and `EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized` seems to indicate repeated connections and disconnections.

Comment: @strugee Any specific ideas what to look for?

Comment: @l0b0 interesting, are you sure you don't have any dhcp client running at the time of disconnect. Maybe if you could share a dmesg log, somebody could catch on.

Comment: After stopping the `dhcpcd` service I now get `authentication with [MAC address] timed out` whenever it tries to connect.

Comment: Could this be relevant: `WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect`? Tried with both the generated and the literal `psk` value.

Comment: After `wpa_supplicant` fails multiple times,, it stops finding the relevant SSID in the scans every 5 seconds. It doesn't seem to be connected - `dhcpcd -4 [interface]` fails after a timeout.

Comment: @l0b0 look for in what? Also, you _still_ haven't told us why you're stopping dhcpd.

Comment: @strugee: Some indication of what is actually wrong. *Both* devices work with very little issue in Windows (it takes a while to connect, like a minute or so). When I read *some* of the instructions it simply said to do that first. I've tried with and without `dhcpcd` running.

Comment: @l0b0 unless you know you need a static IP and/or BootP, you shouldn't be stopping `dhcpd`. The answer is probably that you don't need those things.

Comment: @strugee Don't need which things? I've tried at least three different ways of connecting to Wi-Fi (`wifi-menu`, `wpa_cli` and `wpa_supplicant`), and in between giving absolutely no useful debugging output (`wifi-menu`) and hundreds of lines (`wpa_supplicant`) I haven't any idea what is wrong yet.

Comment: @l0b0 I meant a static IP or BootP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the main problem is the BT Home Hub version 4 which came with the Internet subscription. After disabling 5 GHz wireless, WPS, 802.11 n, automatic channel selection and setting security to WPA2 only, I'm now able to get a connection within seconds in both Ubuntu and Windows, and a very sketchy connection (as in, ~30 seconds connectivity every few minutes with `wpa_supplicant`) with an up-to-date Arch Linux.

Update: After using NetworkManager (`nmcli dev wifi connect SSID password PASSWORD`) I am getting what seems like a little more stability - it still drops out every few minutes or so.

Windows also does not always get a connection for several minutes, after which it seems stable.

(I also tried connecting an old ADSL router, not realising that it cannot understand a VDSL signal.)

Answer (score 6):

Did you setup your passphrase with `wpa_passphrase`? e.g

```
%> wpa_passphrase SSID passphrase
network={
        ssid="SSID"
        #psk="passphrase"
        psk=28964ba6ea8b8f3a0db1c4414b327da253d0af5d4f4adccec0f8abf5b05b10f8
}
```

Otherwise `wpa_supplicant -B -i [wireless device] -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/cli.conf` won't work at all

Comment: Interesting. Do you have to hash the password, or put it in as quoted/unquoted plaintext?

Comment: @l0b0 it was all generated by wpa_passphrase, no, only hashed version is required

Comment: So I need to copy that string manually to `wpa_cli`? Isn't there an easier way to do this? It seems I'm connected afterwards (at least there are no error messages), so I'll award this answer.

Comment: @l0b0 I've never thought about wpa_cli before. Normally I'd run wpa_supplicant directly (remember specify the wireless interface and the driver) with the generated config file. Then I check the output of `dmesg` to see if it's associated

Comment: According to the `wpa_supplicant.conf` the `psk` option seems to be the *unhashed* key. And you should have a key management specification, like: `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK` as well.

Comment: You are god incarnate. This worked perfectly; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

wifi-menu should set up your passphrase for you. There shouldn't be a need to set it up manually. <strike>Check the configuration for wlp0s29f7u5 in /etc/conf.d/network-wireless@. Also check /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf to see if the information is correct.</strike>

Another thing, unless you are trying to set up a static address you shouldn't need to stop the dhcpcd service. If it is static then make sure you declare that in /etc/conf.d/network-wireless@

Finally provide and ip. 'dhcpcd wlp0s26f7u5' for dhcp

or for static do the following.

ip addr add "your ip"/24 dev wlp0s26f7u5
ip route add default via

**EDIT**

The file I was trying to refer to is in netctl. Here is mine:

```
[verdict@sparky ~]$ cat /etc/netctl/wlo1-ZombieNet 
Description='Automatically generated profile by wifi-menu'
Interface=wlo1
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa
ESSID=ZombieNet
IP=dhcp
Key=<my password>
```

Comment: And btw I don't use the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file at all. You don't have to with wifi-menu.

Comment: I have verified the password in `wifi-menu`, the generated file and the `wpa_passphrase` output file multiple times to no avail. The same password works on another (Ubuntu) machine, so that is *not* the issue.