# How to resume pacman package downloads?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I'm trying to install some updates while on a [sketchy connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96364/how-to-debug-repeated-wi-fi-disconnections-in-arch-linux) in Arch Linux. What is the best way to do that?

```
while ! pacman --noconfirm --needed --refresh --upgrade
do
    :
done
```

took over 90 minutes to complete. Possibly this is because I used the strangely named `--upgrade` option which is for *reinstalling* packages rather than doing a package upgrade (`--sysupgrade`).

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't `pacman`'s default behaviour: if the package has been successfully downloaded (ie., is not considered corrupt either due to incomplete downloading or a failed hash sum), then pacman shouldn't download the same package again. If the package has been partially downloaded, `pacman` will resume downloading where it left off without you doing anything special.

You could also look at using a wrapper like [Powerpill](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Powerpill) to assist with downloading over a flaky connection.

Answer (score 2):

Just new to Arch, so maybe I am missing something.

For me pacman did not resume file downloads by default and together with my flaky Internet connection it was impossible to install packages bigger than about 1MB. It just started over again and again and never finished.

After some investigation in the pacman.conf docs, I used...

`DisableDownloadTimeout`

`XferCommand = /usr/bin/wget --passive-ftp -c -O %o %u`

...as well as...

`UseDelta    = 0.7` # a little extra

...to mitigate Germany's mobile Internet shortcomings. Now it resumes just fine.

Comment: Interesting settings. `UseDelta = 0.7` is the default according to `man pacman.conf`.

Comment: Ah, right. Initially I wanted to change that value but then struggled to understand the description and left it as it was predefined in pacman.conf. :)